# SQLite Internals - Records

Tags: sqlite, storage, database-internals, record

Hey I'm trying to wrap my head around SQLite data storage, specifically how it is storing Records. I've found a book [The Definitive guide to SQLlite](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4302-3226-1), where the author explains internal record format (Figure 9-5, page 351):

Given table:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT * FROM episodes ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
id   season  name
---  ------  --------------------
0    1       Good News Bad News
```

Its internal record format is:

```
| 04 | 01 | 01 | 49 |   | 00 | 01 | Good News Bad News |
```

> "The header is 4 bytes long. The header size reflects this and itself is encoded as a single byte. The first type, corresponding to the id field, is a 1-byte signed integer. The second type, corresponding to the season field, is as well. The name type entry is an odd number, meaning it is a text value. Its size is therefore given by (49-13)/2=18 bytes."

Specifically I'm curious about `TEXT` attribute, in the example above we have a string of length 18 characters. And the rule for `TEXT` in SQLite is as follows:

```
Type Value     Meaning   Length of Data
----------     -------   --------------------
N>13 and odd   TEXT      (N-13)/2
```

What hapenns though when the string is longer ? It'll get out of range of that one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Either the book authors describe some really ancient version of SQLite, or they make a mistake when they say "[t]he header size [...] is encoded as a single byte."

[Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) that "describes and defines the on-disk database file format used by all releases of SQLite since version 3.0.0 (2004-06-18)" states that

> The record format makes extensive use of the **variable-length integer** or **varint** representation of 64-bit signed integers[...]
>
> A record contains a header and a body, in that order. **The header begins with a single varint which determines the total number of bytes in the header**. [...] Following the size varint are one or more additional varints, one per column.

while

> A variable-length integer or "varint" is a static Huffman encoding of 64-bit twos-complement integers that uses less space for small positive values. A varint is between 1 and 9 bytes in length.

so

> The serial type varints for large strings and BLOBs might extend to two or three byte varints

which certainly allows them to represent pretty long values.

Comment: I think you and the author are saying the same thing. The sentence "...encoded as a single byte." is same as yours "The header begins with a single varint which determines the total number of bytes in the header", which in the example is 1 byte, because the header is only 4 bytes long.

Comment: Therefore if my assumption is correct and if the string was longer, for example 144 characters long (00000011 10101100 as varint) we'd need 2 bytes, not just one. Then the table would look like this: | 06 | 01 | 01 | 301| ...

Comment: No, I don't believe these are the same things: "encoded as a single byte" and "a single varint". Particularly because the former caused your confusion in the first place.

Comment: Well I was more curious about the string situation. A single varint of length 1 byte, maybe that's how the author meant it ? Sounds about right to me, or am I missing something else ?